# Can't access model elements in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using Ionic 3.

I have a model that looks something like this:

```
export interface Visit{
    employeeNumber:{
        fieldID: string,
        value: string
    }
    patientRecord:{
        fieldID: string,
        value: string
    }
}
```

Then in my ts I have something like this: `visit = {} as Visit;`

And I was trying to tie (I don't know if that's the correct word), for example, `visit.employeeNumber.value` to an input field using `[(ngModel)]`

But it did not work. (I get an undefined error). However, if I change my model like this

```
export interface Visit{
    employeeNumber: string;
    patientRecord: string;
}
```

Then I go ahead and do the same thing, but instead, I put `visit.employeeNumber` in the `[(ngModel)]` and it works. Is there anyway I can make it work using the original model I explained?

EDIT: I think I see the error. I'm using semicolons in the first model when I should be using a comma. I'm trying that out.

EDIT 2: It didn't work. I've modified the model to show how I changed it. The error I'm getting says `undefined is not an object (evaluating this.visit.employeeNumber.value = var1)` var 1 being a variable I'm assigning to check if the value is being assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get "an undefined error" because angular needs to set `visit.employeeNumber.value`, but `visit.employeeNumber` is undefined.

Initialize the object with valid values. Or at least initialize `visit.employeeNumber` and `visit.patientRecord` with empty objects.